# Static assert whether or not add operation is available

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, static-assert

I'm trying to make a static assert that checks whether type A can be added to type B. Is there any way to check whether template type A is addable to template type B at compile time? A and B could really be anything at all.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean by _addable_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [is_detected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), you may do something like:

```
template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
using sum_t = decltype(std::declval<LHS>() + std::declval<RHS>());

template <typename LHS, typename RHS> 
using has_sum = is_detected<sum_t, LHS, RHS>;
```

Comment: Interesting that there's no `is_detected_v` . Still, one could do 
`template <typename LHS, typename RHS> 
constexpr auto has_sum_v = std::experimental::is_detected<sum_t, LHS, RHS>::value;` . . . `static_assert(has_sum_v<int,float>);`